# How to increase value on key element in map?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a map in c++ with following pairs:

```
pair<int, int>(1, 40) 
pair<int, int>(2, 30) 
pair<int, int>(3, 60) 
pair<int, int>(4, 20) 
pair<int, int>(5, 50) 
pair<int, int>(6, 50) 
pair<int, int>(7, 10)
```

How can I increase pair with key "1" by 2? 
so how can I get this:

````
pair<int, int>(1, 42) 
pair<int, int>(2, 30) 
pair<int, int>(3, 60) 
pair<int, int>(4, 20) 
pair<int, int>(5, 50) 
pair<int, int>(6, 50) 
pair<int, int>(7, 10) 
```
````

Comment: please post a minimal code

Comment: myMap[1] +=2; should do the job

Comment: or `myMap.at(1) += 2`. Difference is that if map doesn't contain value for that key it will throw exception, Oblivion version will insert to map value `2` for key `1` in such case.